# In JavaScript, how can I check if an HTML form is valid?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Before submitting my form with jQuery after using `event.preventDefault()`, I need to check if my form has some validation errors (empty required fields, wrong data in "email" input, etc.) before submitting it programmatically (which will bypass the HTML5 validation and create a useless reloading returning a Django form error).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's fairly easy !

When submitting a form, some "invalid" meta datas are added to the falsly inputs. With this, we can use a neat little  CSS selector  to  detect if  we have some incorrect  fields :

```
let invalid_fields = $("form :invalid");
```

We now have a list of invalid fields or not. The world is fairly well made so every array has a "length" property. We can check this to determine if we're safe to submit the form or not :

```
if(invalid_fields.length == 0){
     //Do some funny things
    $("form).submit();
}
```

If the length is greater than 0, we have an error. If not, everything is good :)